# Having Repositories references in MVC controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, nhibernate, design-patterns, architecture

I am working on enterprise application using MVC, Nhibernate and IOC container.

I three tiers:

DAL - Nhibernate Data Repositories

```
public class CustomerRepository : Repository<int>,ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {

    }
}
```

BLL - Business Layer

```
public class CustomerManager
{
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _repository;
    public CustomerManager(ICustomerRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public IList<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll<Customer>();
    }
}
```

Presentation - MVC controller

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
private readonly ICustomerRepository _repository;
private readonly CustomerManager _manager;

public HomeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ICustomerRepository repository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _repository = repository;
        _manager = new CustomerManager(_repository);
    }
```

I am using IOC container to register unit of work and CustomerRepository objects. The IOC container is working fine.

What is bugging me about this solution is that I have CustomerRepository reference in the controller. Is this architecture fine or there is a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need/have a `IUnitOfWork` or `ICustomerRepository` in the controller, with the IoC container you should be able to register the `CustomerManager` and then do this:

```
private readonly CustomerManager _manager;

public HomeController(CustomerManager customerManager)
{
    _manager = customerManager;
}
```

The IoC container should understand the dependency chain and inject all the various dependencies as needed.

I.e. MVC will try and get a `HomeController` from the IoC container, which in turn needs a `CustomerManager`... so the IoC container will try and get a `CustomerManager`, which in turn needs a `ICustomerRepository`... so the IoC container will try... you get the point.

I would also go the the extent of extracting an interface from `CustomerManager` (`ICustomerManager` probably) to remove the coupling and make testing the Controller even easier.

Comment: As not-native to all this ASP.NET thing .. I assume that you guys use name `Manager` for classes that describe service-layer structures, or have I got confused there?

Comment: @tereško I was simply just copying what was in the question. I wouldn't say it was a _ASP.NET thing_ at all. In fact, I would generally say ASP.NET (MVC) naming conventions beyond the UI level shouldn't really deviate from other languages... it's all the same :-)

Answer (score 1):

All of your business logic should be in the Manager class, so you shouldn't need a dependency on the Repository in your controller. The controller should just be calling fairly high-level methods in your Manager class.